# Averaging and updating columns with NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I recently received answers for a survey where a few questions were optional.

I want to take the average values of the questions that were asked and fill them in to all the rows with the same ID's even though some values are NULL.

This is what I have so far:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["CID"];
        echo " <br>";
        $avg = $row["AVG(CQ1)"];
        $name = $row["CID"];
        $sql = "UPDATE CES2_RESULTS_UA SET CQ1 = $avg WHERE CID = '$name'";
```

The problem is that none of the values in the columns are being updated.

Comment: echo $sql; print it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply that to your code. Then come back and tell us if anything came of it.

Comment: also you have not put full code here .. check whether you are getting any error in your query or not.

Comment: `$row["AVG(CQ1)"]` -- > for the sake of all that is holy, use aliases in your queries

Comment: I held off long as I could here; I'll pass.